# How to add new model to nested model rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, nested-forms, mode

I have  models nested like this

Paper has_many Questions
Question has_one Tag

the data for both Paper and question were supplied at the same time by a nested form and then shown
as a document, Now I want to add a functionality where users can add comment to each questions. How can I achieve this?

This is my Paper

```
class PapersController < ApplicationController
#I have removed other methods to keep it simple
#this is creating three question and one tag that is filled via a form      
      def new
        @paper = Paper.new
        3.times do 
           question = @paper.questions.build
           1.times { question.build_tag } 
         end

      end
end

#Paper model    
class Paper < ActiveRecord::Base

              has_many :questions, dependent: :destroy

              accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions, reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes['content'].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true

end

#Question Model    
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :paper
      has_many   :comments, dependent: :destroy
      has_one    :tag, dependent: :destroy

      accepts_nested_attributes_for :tag

end

#Tag model
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :question

end
```

Now I want to add a Comment to each question so that the question can be clicked and view in another page with its comments.

I don't have any QuestionsController, TagController yet

Comment: SO is not the site for this question. if you haven't gone through a Rails tutorial, go through one first and post questions when you have issues with a certain code.

Comment: This isn't a place where we help you from scratch , at least do some homework first . Come back when you have tried and stuck at some place.

Comment: Guy thanks for advice but Isn't is obvious from the question that I have done something already? You could answer in two lines but chose to give a lecture.

Comment: we are not lecturing you.  Questions like this one get closed because it requires users to answer with a very long/big code just to be acceptable as an answer.  If you truly did implement the survey and question parts, you shouldn't have any issues at all with adding another model.  if you can change your question to specific code that you're having issues with, we'll be more than happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

[**has_many**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-association)

```
#app/models/question.rb
Class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :comments
end

#app/models/comment.rb
Class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :question
end
```

You'll want to check out the [has_many association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-association):

[image]

---

**Create**

If you wanted to create comments for a question, you should look at this [RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/262-trees-with-ancestry?view=comments). I'd do:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :questions do
    resources :comments # -> domain.com/questions/1/comments/new
end

#app/controllers/comments.rb
def new 
    @comment = Comment.new
end 

def create
    @comment = Comment.new(comments_params)
end

private
def comments_params
     params.require(:comments).permit(:your, :attributes).merge(question_id: params[:question_id])
end
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, can you check I have modified the question.